# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Is it possible to have multiple Elastic Beanstalk apps in single git repo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I have a worker app and an api service which are both for the same project and I want them using same tooling. But I am not sure if you can deploy to different EBs from same repo using single config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this like me there's now documentation from AWS on how to setup an elastic beanstalk project for this kind of thing:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebcli-compose.html

Basically you add an env.yaml for each subfolder

```
~/project-name
|-- component-a
|   `-- env.yaml
`-- component-b
    `-- env.yaml
```

You can then instantiate each component like so:

`~/workspace/project-name$ eb init --modules component-a component-b`

Additional commands seem to be similar to other elastic beanstalk commands with the additional `--modules` flag. [See documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebcli-compose.html).

Answer (score -1):

I do this, so allow me to share my experience.

Enable your application to be started in multiple ways. We run Node.js, so we have something like this:

```
node app.js // webserver
node app.js worker // worker
```

The app.js detects that `worker` argument was provided and kicks off a worker process in the background, `WorkerService.run()`

When we deploy, the startup command, `NodeCommand` parameter for Node.js, runs and the appropriate version of the app is run.

For checking health, we still run the webserver, but it isn't handling requests. As the worker runs, we update a file indicating the last time the worker ran. The health endpoint, `/health/worker` checks that this file was updated within the last 5 minutes. If it's been longer than 5 minutes, that endpoint responds with a 5xx error and the instance will soon be deregistered and filtered out.

Comment: I am confused about wether I should deploy to two environments or not. Because I think environment are for checking wether app is running in production or staging. So should I use it for two separate services?

Comment: To clarify, I run one Beanstalk "Application". I create one new "Application Version" for each version of the code base that I deploy. I have 5 different beanstalk "Environments", each with different invocations, that I specify use that new "Application Version" that I created.